# Automatically naming output txt file in Python

Tags: python-3.x, output, rename

I have 4 lists called I_list, Itiso, ItHDKR and Itperez and I would like to receive .txt output files with the data of these lists. I am trying to make Python rename automatically the name of the .txt output files in terms of some of my input data. In this way, the .txt output files will always have different names.

Now I am programming the following commands:

```
Horizontal_radiation = []
Isotropic_radiation = []
HDKR_radiation = []
Perez_radiation = []

Horizontal = open("outputHorizontal.txt", 'w')
Isotropic = open("outputIsotropic.txt", 'w')
HDKR = open("outputHDKR.txt", 'w')
Perez = open("outputPerez.txt", 'w')

for i in I_list:
      Horizontal_radiation.append(i)
for x in Itiso:
      Isotropic_radiation.append(x)
for y in ItHDKR:
      HDKR_radiation.append(y)
for z in Itperez:
      Perez_radiation.append(z)        

Horizontal.write(str(Horizontal_radiation))
Isotropic.write(str(Isotropic_radiation))
HDKR.write(str(HDKR_radiation))
Perez.write(str(Perez_radiation))

Horizontal.close()
Isotropic.close()
HDKR.close()
Perez.close()
```

As you can see, the name of the .txt output file is fixed as "outputHorizontal.txt" (the first one). Is there any way to change this name and put it according to a input? For example, one of my inputs is the latitude, as 'lat'. I am trying to make the output file name be expressed in terms of 'lat', in this way everytime I run the program the name would be different, because now I always get the same name and the file is overwritten.

Thank you very much people, kind regards.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass a string variable as the output file name. For example you could move the file declarations after you add elements to the lists (and before you write them) and use

```
Horizontal = open(str(Horizontal_radiation[0]), 'w')
```

Or just add a timestamp to the file name if it's all about don't overwriting files

```
Horizontal = open("horizontal-%s".format(datetime.today()), 'w')
```